# KVS Should ID be in the document if it's a key?

Tags: database-design, nosql

Assume that I have a KVS database where keys are the document IDs. The documents are JSON and XML, and it is possible to get the document ID in them. For example:

```
c62a3ecd-696b-4c9e:{"document-id": "c62a3ecd-696b-4c9e", ... }
```

Is it good practice to have the ID in both?

If Not, should retrieval plant it in the JSON/XML? And how would we know if the database corrupt?

If yes, would every retrieval need to double check they're the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the identifier in the JSON or XML value of KV database is not a good idea. It will duplicate the information and might become out-of-sync if you "clone" document.  That is, if you want to insert a new document based on a previously stored document, you will need to update the `document["uid"]` field.

Simply said, you do not need to store the UID in the value, because it is already stored in the key.

But, in the code, when you retrieve a given object you can associate it with the identifier. So that you can update the correct record document.

In JavaScript, you will end up with the following

```js
function ref(uid) { /* retrieve the JSON document with the given UID */ }
function update(uid, object) { /* update the record UID with the JSON object OBJECT */ }


// let's say you know the identifier (UID) of a document, you can retrieve
// it with the `ref` function

let uid = 'P4X432'
let myDocument = ref(uid)

// update one field of the document

myDocument["website"] = "https://hyper.dev"

// now you need to save it, re-use the original identifier

update(uid, myDocument)
```

So in the end, you might end up with a JavaScript Object, or class that looks like the following:

```
myDatabaseRecord = {
  "uid": "P4X432", 
  "document": {
    "website": "https://hyper.dev", ...
  }
}
```

That is how mongodb clients do it. If I remember correctly, in nodejs mongodb client library, `objectid` use a special key `$id` to describe the identifier of the document, like:

```js
object = { 
  "$id": "P4X432",
  "website": "https://hyper.dev",
  ...
}
```

Everything but `$id` will be stored in value of the KV database.  That appraoch works to the extent that it will require to do a partial copy (!) to construct the JSON document that will be stored in the database (note: mutation is not possible in that case), you will end up with less performant code.

What is live in the code is different from what is alive in the database. The important thing to keep in mind is that **in the code** you need to keep track of the identifier of the documents.